# Fix permissions on the /etc/ directory Mac

Tags: macos, file-permissions, macos-highsierra

I accidentally changed all the owner permissions of the /etc/ directory in Mac OS High Sierra to user:_www when trying to change the ownership of a website folder.

I guess these files usually have root:wheel permissions.
I tried to change back with:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /etc
```

But I got the error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 503, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

So, I guess that the sudo won't work properly due to the permissions on that folder.

Is there a way to change the permissions back on that folder and subfolders?

Comment: The 'official' way to restore correct perms is to re-install the OS from Recovery. that should leave any user data untouched. Otherwise you're fighting SIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. Get a root shell without sudo by entering single-user mode: Reboot while holding down <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
2. Follow the on-screen instructions to remount the root partition read/write: `mount -uw /`
3. Run your command you wanted to run, *but this time leave off the `sudo`, since you're already in a root shell (not to mention that you already know sudo is busted)*.
4. Reboot back into normal multiuser mode: `reboot`

Comment: This did not work for me.  Maybe because the /etc/sudoers file ownership had changed.  The terminal said "root" but when trying to `chown` the files, it complained about the permissiosn of the /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: @jonnyjandles I should have specified that since you already had a root shell and already knew that `sudo` was busted, that you should leave off the `sudo` from the front of your command. I'll edit my Answer to make that clear.

Comment: I also found a way to get root from the terminal by allowing root user.  The command `dsenableroot` was allowed from the admin cli.  I could then log out of the user and log in as the root user and access terminal as root.

Comment: @jonnyjandles If leaving off the `sudo` in step 3 doesn't work, please let me know the exact error message you get. Also, the output of `ls -leO@ /etc/sudoers` (that's a "capital oh" in there) would be helpful.